# dell inspiron n4010 wi fi not connected

Tags: wireless, 10.04

I'm using dell n4010 lapt0p and i installed ubuntu 10.04 desktop edition but i'm unable to connect with wireless network?
my lspci output is

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4727 (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

and my iwconfig output is:

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

pan0      no wireless extensions.
```

my rfkill output is

```
rfkill list all
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and my  `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`
output is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

now what am i do please help me?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Comment: @chili555 i've added the output of lspci -nn -d 14e4: please check the same. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: ok,i'll try....

Comment: not able to connect using this....i intalled all of these but no success

Comment: Does it scan and see networks? sudo iwlist eth1 scan. Does it try to connect but just never authenticate? Is the driver wl loaded? lsmod | grep wl. If not,load it: sudo modprobe wl

Comment: no i'm not able  to scan ....

Comment: iwlist eth1 scan it show that interface does not support scanning...

Comment: Is the driver wl loaded? Did you try loading it to see if there is a warning or error?

Comment: error inserting wl (/lib/modules/2.6.32-21-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
FATAL: Error running install command for wl

Comment: I suggest you retrace the steps above: 'sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic;
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source;
sudo modprobe wl' If the module still doesn't load cleanly, check: dmesg | grep wl